# No more vertex groups on most modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

Hi I've noticed that on blender 2.8 I could use vertex groups for all the modifiers but now on 2.9 it seems it doesn't have this feature anymore, at least not on every modifier.
I need the vertex groups modifier to smooth some parts of the mesh without slpitting it into different meshes, can anybody help me?

Comment: What modifier are you talking about? Subdiv (no vertex group, never), smooth (has one)?

Comment: I was talking about subdiv, but I just wanted to smooth some are of my mesh like the subdiv do

Comment: You can't use vertex groups on the subdivision surface modifier. Maybe you are thinking of the bevel modifier ?

Comment: I saw also in the bevel isn't available anymore the vertex groups option, I have this low poly mesh and I need to create some smooth surfaces, what do you suggest to use to accomplish this?

Comment: Bevel has vertex group option. Have a look to "limit method".

Comment: thank you so much!